# WCF -- How to disable client's ability to generate proxies and see the "you have created a service" page

Tags: .net, wcf

I was wondering if there was a way in WCF to prevent the client from generating proxies by using the svcutil?  Also, is there a way to prevent the client from being able to type the service address in the web brower and having the default instructional page come up -- the one that reads, "You have created a service" and tells the client how to generate a proxy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *believe* you're looking for the `<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />` setting under the serviceBehavior (in web.config).

**EDIT** Also, probably want to remove the mex endpoint.